# Table in Svelte doesn't update on prop change

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte

I have a table in Svelte that uses a prop "things" that stores the data to be displayed as an array. When I create the table element in a parent class I pass in a store called $submissionsArr. $submissionsArr is linked to a firebase realtime database - whenever an element is added, changed or removed, $submissionsArr is updated automatically (this bit works fine; in the update I assign $submissionsArr back to itself so that Svelte registers that it has changed). However, when $submissionsArr updates the table does not.

Table.svelte class:

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    export let things;
    export let title;
    export let note;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function handleClick(thing, col) {
        dispatch("cellClick", {
            cell: thing,
        });
    }

    $: colNames = Object.keys(things[0]);
    let sortBy = { col: "", ascending: true };

    $: sort = (column) => {
        if (sortBy.col == column) {
            sortBy.ascending = !sortBy.ascending;
        } else {
            sortBy.col = column;
            sortBy.ascending = true;
        }

        // Modifier to sorting function for ascending or descending
        let sortModifier = sortBy.ascending ? 1 : -1;

        // works best for strings; not so good for numbers
        let sort = (a, b) =>
            a[column] < b[column]
                ? -1 * sortModifier
                : a[column] > b[column]
                ? 1 * sortModifier
                : 0;

        things = things.sort(sort);
    };
</script>

<div>{title}</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each colNames as col}
                <th on:click={sort(col)}>{col} &varr;</th>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {#each things as thing}
            <tr>
                {#each colNames as col}
                    <td on:click={handleClick(thing, col)}>{thing[col]}</td>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>{note}</div>
```

Construction of Table.svelte component in a parent class SubmissionsTable.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { submissionsArr } from "./stores.mjs";
    import Table from "./Table.svelte";
</script>

{#if $submissionsArr.length > 0}
        <Table
            things={$submissionsArr}
            title="Submissions"
            note="Click on a table cell to edit submission and view comments"
            on:cellClick={handleCellClick}
        />
{/if}
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use  [Svelte Store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store) (subscribe/unsibscribe)

Comment: I am already using Svelte stores ($submissionsArr is a writable store defined in stores.mjs file). I don't want to reference any store in the Table.svelte class directly because I am reusing this class several times for different purposes. I would like to keep the export statements and props.